# Gradle doesn't work after migrating to Android Studio 3.1.1

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-studio-3.0

Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.1/gradle-3.1.1.pom'. Received status code 500 from server: Internal Server Error
Enable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project

I have enabled proxy setting either. If I click on the above URL, The POM file would be downloaded. It works fine in browser. Which make gradle to throw 500 internal server error? Thanks in advance.

Note:
Actually that maven URL has been blocked by proxy. But If I hit this URL in browsers, It does works fine. How can we enable it AS? and Why AS is blocking it?

Comment: It's because your network connectivity is ofline Kindly connect to network connectivity

Comment: @abhil-nair Thanks. Great answer!!!!!!!!! But It doesn't work for me.

Comment: Exact same issue I am facing. @Praveen2Gemini did you find any solution to this ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, what version of AS you had used. There are some issues, that many developers bumped into, after the update up to AS 3.1 and later. You should try to update to the latest version of Android Gradle Plugin and Gradle according to the table [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html#updating-gradle). I hope, that it solves the problem. It worked out in my case at least.

Comment: Actually that maven URL has been blocked by proxy. But If I hit this URL in browsers, It does works fine. How can we enable it AS? and Why AS is blocking it?

Comment: @Praveen2Gemini I have same issue, did you find any solution?